# React/Socket.io messaging app works locally, Builds successfully on heroku, returns 404 on load

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, socket.io

I am trying to deploy a simple chat room app on Heroku using Express, React and Socket.io. The app runs perfectly fine on my local machine and when I build it on Heroku I get no errors in the build console. I open My Heroku application and get a 404 status. I am not using a database or api's for this application.

Here is the repo if you wanted to look more closely at the code, https://github.com/tarthurf/chatticus please make sure you are viewing the **heroku** branch.

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const app = express();
const server = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io") (server);

// Define middleware here
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
// Serve up static assets (usually on heroku)
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
} else {
  app.use(express.static("client/public"));
}

// Define API routes here

// Send every other request to the React app
// Define any API routes before this runs
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/build/index.html"));
});

io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log("Socket connected!")
...

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(` ==> API server now on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

server package.json

```
{
  "name": "chatticus",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "yarn": "1.22.4",
    "node": "12.16.1"
  },
  "description": "A simple chat web application",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run start:prod || npm run start:dev",
    "start:prod": "node server.js",
    "start:dev": "concurrently \"nodemon --ignore 'client/*'\" \"npm run client\"",
    "client": "cd client && npm run start",
    "install": "cd client && yarn install",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.4",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.7",
    "postcss-cli": "^7.1.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.4.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.29",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.13.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.13.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.11",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "if-env": "^1.0.4",
    "react-cool-onclickoutside": "^1.5.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Client package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run watch:css && react-scripts start",
    "build": "npm run build:css && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build:css": "postcss src/assets/tailwind.css -o src/assets/main.css", 
    "watch:css": "postcss src/assets/tailwind.css -o src/assets/main.css"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Home.js (main page) socket connection

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import UseForm from '../utils/useForm';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Username from './Username';

// Creating socket for user session
const socket = io()
```

Console on page load
[image]

Comment: I took a look at your repository, and I couldn't find `client/build` which is used as the public path when `NODE_ENV` is production. This is likely what's causing the issue. On a side note `heroku logs --source app` may help you debug this situation :)

Comment: I set up my build folder in my client, still getting a 404. I will check heroku logs to see if i cant pinpoint what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check any URLs for localhost in them. You can omit that portion and leave them as relative paths in order to work on Heroku.